# How to pass optional keyword named group to views.py in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a search filter of an ecommerce site.

**Current Situation:**
When user select each platform filter, the platform name will be appended to URL and display the filtered result.

**My approach:**

url.py

```
url(r'^search/(?P<product_slug>[0-9a-z-]+)$', CustomSearchView(), name='search_result_detail'),enter code here

url(r'^search/(?P<product_slug>[0-9a-z-]+)_(?P<platform_slug>[0-9a-z-]+)$', CustomSearchView(),
    name='search_result_platform'),

url(r'^search/(?P<product_slug>[0-9a-z-]+)_(?P<platform_slug>[0-9a-z-]+)_(?P<platform_slug2>[0-9a-z-]+)$',
    CustomSearchView(), name='search_result_platform2'),

url(r'^search/(?P<product_slug>[0-9a-z-]+)_(?P<platform_slug>[0-9a-z-]+)_'
    r'(?P<platform_slug2>[0-9a-z-]+)_(?P<platform_slug3>[0-9a-z-]+)$',
    CustomSearchView(), name='search_result_platform3'),
```

**Main Question:**
I didn't want to limit the filtering number. So if there are 20 platform filters, I need to create 20 URLs. Definitely it's not a smart way. Any other smart way to avoid creating a batches of URL?

views.py

```
def __call__(self, request, product_slug, platform_slug=None,platform_slug2=None,platform_slug3 = None
             ,platform_slug4 = None,platform_slug5 = None):

if platform_slug is None:
        self.product_review_list = SearchResult.objects.filter(products__slug=product_slug)
else:
        self.product_review_list = SearchResult.objects.filter(Q(products__slug=product_slug),
        Q(platform__slug=platform_slug)|(Q(platform__slug=platform_slug2)|Q(platform__slug=platform_slug3)
                                         |Q(platform__slug=platform_slug4)|Q(platform__slug=platform_slug5)))
```

Comment: This sounds to me like you should use `GET`- parameters, and not separate resources (paths)

Comment: `*args` or `**kwargs` would be help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this kind of filtering is a job for GET parameters, not paths.

The URL pattern should just be `r'^search/$'`, and you call it via `/search/?platform_slug=x&platform_slug=y&platform_slug=z`. Then, in the view, you can just use `__in` to filter:

```
def custom_search_view(request):
    product_review_list = SearchResult.objects.filter(products__slug__in=request.GET.getlist('platform_slug')
```

One other point. You must **absolutely not** use classes like this in your URLs and then set attributes on `self`. That is not threadsafe and will cause all sorts of problems. If you really need to use a class, subclass the generic View class and use it in the URLs as `CustomSearchView.as_view()`, then override `get()` or `post()`.

Comment: Thanks daniel. Since my client requested that no get query could be added in URL for SEO practice. So is there any way to bypass the get query method or any way can rewrite the URL to be query-free URL?